# Не работает тест на Mocha

Tags: node.js, mocha

После обновления Mocha не могу запустить даже простой тест. Вот его код:

```
const assert = require('assert');

it('should complete this test', function (done) {
   return new Promise(function (resolve) {
     assert.ok(true);
     resolve();
  })
 .then(done);
});
```

Я взял этот код из https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#boom-breaking-changes

Я понял, что он теперь выкидывает исключение:

> Error: Resolution method is overspecified. Specify a callback *or* return a Promise; not both.

Но как его сделать рабочим я так и не понял. Использую:

```
node -v 6.9.4
mocha -v 3.2.0
```

Как запустить этот код теперь в новом и правильном формате?

Comment: Там же написано, что этот код и должен вбрасывать ошибку. Что именно вы хотите?

Answer (score 0):

Вы пытаетесь использовать в тестовом сценарии одновременно и `done` - функцию и возвращать `Promise`. Так делать нельзя, нужно выбрать что-то одно (о чем собственно и говориться в сообщении об ошибке).

Варианта модификации тестового сценария у вас всего два:

1. Выбросить `done` - функцию:

   ```
   it('should complete this test', function () {
       return new Promise(function (resolve) {
           assert.ok(true);
           resolve();
       });
   });
   ```
2. Выбросить `Promise`:

   ```
   it('should complete this test', function (done) {
       setTimeout(function () {
           assert.ok(true);
           done();
       }, 2);
   });
   ```

Какой из вариантов выбрать - решайте сами.